# Underlying technique of Android's FaceDetector

Tags: android, java-native-interface, fft, face-detection

I'm implementing a face tracker on Android, and as a literature study, would like to identify the underlying technique of Android's FaceDetector.

Simply put: I want to understand how the `android.media.FaceDetector` classifier works.

A brief Google search didn't yield anything informative, so I thought I'd take a look at the code.

By looking at the Java source code, [`FaceDetector.java`](https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=media/java/android/media/FaceDetector.java), there isn't much to be learned: `FaceDetector` is simply a class that is provided the image dimensions and number of faces, then returns an array of faces.

The Android source [contains the JNI code for this class](https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/neven.git;a=tree). I followed through the function calls, where, reduced to the bare essentials, I learned:

1. The "FaceFinder" is created in [`FaceFinder.c:75`](https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/neven.git;a=blob;f=FaceRecEm/common/src/b_FDSDK/FaceFinder.c;h=b24ac111f98dd5a580849adb72c434a36479b135;hb=HEAD#l75)
2. On line 90, `bbs_MemSeg_alloc` returns a `btk_HFaceFinder` object (which contains the function to actually find faces), essentially copying it the `hsdkA->contextE.memTblE.espArrE` array of the original `btk_HSDK` object initialized within initialize() ([`FaceDetector_jni.cpp:145`](https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/neven.git;a=blob;f=FaceDetector_jni.cpp;h=03bd908bed10527a782b9d74770ffc9be2f4aeb4;hb=HEAD#l145)) by `btk_SDK_create()`
3. It appears that a maze of functions provide each other with pointers and instances of `btk_HSDK`, but nowhere can I find a concrete instantiation of `sdk->contextE.memTblE.espArrE[0]` that supposedly contains the magic.

What I *have* discovered, is a little clue: the JNI code references a FFTEm library that I can't find the source code for. By the looks of it, however, FFT is *Fast Fourier Transform*, which is probably used together with a pre-trained neural network. The only literature I can find that aligns with this theory is [a paper by Ben-Yacoub et al.](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~bfasel/papers/avbpa_face.pdf)

I don't even really know if I'm set on the right path, so any suggestions at all would undoubtedly help.

**Edit:** I've added a +100 bounty for anybody who can give any insight.

Comment: libFFTEm isn't referenced from Android's face detection layer, actually it IS the compiled output of all sources in external/neven

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find the source code! Thanks; this suggests that if it indeed uses Fast Fourier Transforms, there should be some evidence of it in `neven`. However, nothing really jumps out at me.

Comment: It looks like the "Em" in `libFFTEm` may refer to "expectation-maximization," a statistical method used in color-based skin detection.

Comment: There is a project, which extracted the neven face detector library from Android: [https://github.com/lqs/neven](https://github.com/lqs/neven).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on a phone, so can't respond extensively, but Google keywords "neven vision algorithm" pull up some useful papers...

Also, [US patent 6222939](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6222939B1/en) is related.

Possibly also some of the links on http://peterwilliams97.blogspot.com/2008/09/google-picasa-to-have-face-recognition.html might be handy...

Comment: It appears that Google acquired Neven Vision, an object recognition technique based upon various patents filed by Hartmut Neven. I've not found a detailed description of the algorithm, but following up on the patent gives a little insight.

Comment: The [various patents listed on this site](http://www.seobythesea.com/?p=267) give some insight into the technique. It seems to suggest that it heavily relies on [Gabor Wavelets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter#Wavelet_space).

Answer (score 4):

I Found a couple of links too...Not sure if it would help you...

http://code.google.com/p/android-playground-erdao/source/browse/#svn/trunk/SnapFace

http://code.google.com/p/jjil/

http://benosteen.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/face-recognition-much-easier-than-expected/

Comment: Thank you for your response, and those are interesting projects indeed, but I'm looking for some insight into how Android's *built-in* face detector works (`android.media.FaceDetector`).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=1562271

I think I once saw some matlab code doing this in a presentation.
Maybe it's somewhere online.

Greetings,
Lars

Comment: I googled this link here:
Maybe it's the code. I don't know, I don't have matlab or scilab here to try it out. Maybe you have:
http://download.cnet.com/Face-Recognition-in-Fourier-Space/3000-2053_4-10878312.html

Comment: I'm afraid I don't find any evidence of this being the technique that Neven Vision is based on.